# psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation while using COPY in postgresql

Tags: pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using a custom callable to pandas.to_sql(). The below snippet is from [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#insertion-method) for using it

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

def psql_insert_copy(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    """
    Execute SQL statement inserting data

    Parameters
    ----------
    table : pandas.io.sql.SQLTable
    conn : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlalchemy.engine.Connection
    keys : list of str
        Column names
    data_iter : Iterable that iterates the values to be inserted
    """
    # gets a DBAPI connection that can provide a cursor
    dbapi_conn = conn.connection
    with dbapi_conn.cursor() as cur:
        s_buf = StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(s_buf)
        writer.writerows(data_iter)
        s_buf.seek(0)

        columns = ', '.join('"{}"'.format(k) for k in keys)
        if table.schema:
            table_name = '{}.{}'.format(table.schema, table.name)
        else:
            table_name = table.name

        sql = 'COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV'.format(
            table_name, columns)
        cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)
```

but while using this copy functionality, I am getting the error

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for integer: "3.0"
```

This is not a problem with input as this table schemas and values where working initially, when I have used to_sql() function without using the custom callable 'psql_insert_copy()'. I am using sqlalchemy engine for getting the connection cursor

Comment: The error tells you the problem: `select '3.0'::integer; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "3.0"`. You need `select '3'::integer; 3` You can't insert a float into an integer field.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense but I am using the same schema and same values which worked when I didnt use the Postgre Copy and which worked! That is the part confusing me

Comment: `COPY` is just taking what it is given on `STDIN`.  It is the process that produces `s_buff` that is producing '3.0'.  Either `data_iter` or `csv.writer`. Capture the intermediate output to see where.

Comment: I think when we use INSERT if there are some implicit type mismatch with the schema and the inserted rows, it will take care of it, whereas when we use COPY such checks are not given.

Comment: Then your choices are 1) Clean the data to match the types in the table 2) Change the types in the table to match the data 3) Use @SargisKazaryan answer and create a load table that has all varchar fields and clean up there before moving to final table.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using string fields in the table for such actions, or writing the entire (sql) script manually, indicating the types of table fields